# Image Layout issue Xamarin (Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to have a screen with two basic elements, left text & right the image. 
The height of the container element should be as high as the image. The image width is relative to the screen, which influences the height. I tried various variations but each time the image or the image container has extra space under it.

My code shows 3 variants the last one is without an image, the height is fine here:

```
 <StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="Blue">

  <AbsoluteLayout>        
    <StackLayout  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 0.77, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Padding="0, 5, 0, 0" BackgroundColor="Red"  Grid.Column="0" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="Start">        
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Green">
        <Label Text="Titel"/>
        <Label Text="®" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Subtitel" />
    </StackLayout>
     <Image Source="filler.png" BackgroundColor="Aqua" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, 0.33, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, SizeProportional" VerticalOptions="Start"/>      
  </AbsoluteLayout>       

  <AbsoluteLayout>        
    <StackLayout  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 0.77, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Padding="0, 5, 0, 0" BackgroundColor="Blue"  Grid.Column="0"     Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="Start">        
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Green">
        <Label Text="Titel"/>
        <Label Text="®" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Subtitel" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, 0.33, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, SizeProportional" BackgroundColor="Lime">
      <Image Source="filler.png" BackgroundColor="Silver" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </AbsoluteLayout>  

  <AbsoluteLayout>        
    <StackLayout  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 0.77, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Padding="0, 5, 0, 0" BackgroundColor="Blue"  Grid.Column="0"     Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="Start">        
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Green">
        <Label Text="Titel"/>
        <Label Text="®" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Subtitel" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, 0.33, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, SizeProportional" BackgroundColor="Olive">         
    </StackLayout>
  </AbsoluteLayout> 

</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Where is the extra space coming from ? Should i use a different kind of layout (Grid layout had the same outcome) ?

Comment: Dont you agree with me that you have a lot of Layouts nested to each other? I cannot really know what is the final image you are trying to reach :) have you considered simplifying your design abit ? it is bad for performance anyway :) 
My advice to you is using GorillaPlayer or any Designer apps available , it will make your life much easier

Comment: imo it is a pretty easy design, the repeated blocks are just for testing. I will try out those apps thanks.

Comment: well think about it :) an element insdie a stacklayout which is inside an absolutelayout which is inside a stacklayout which is inside a grid multiply by three , that is a lot of plates to hold :) Try to avoid absolute layouts